# How to add onfocus to a z3c.form input

Tags: python, plone, z3c.form

I am developing a site in plone and am currently writing a form using python and z3c.forms

Currently I am using an interface to define form fields like...

```
class IMyInterface(Interface):

    name = schema.TextLine(
            title=_(u"Name"),
            default=_(u"Name")
        )
```

and then assigning to fields like...

```
fields = field.Fields(IMyInterface)
```

this is then rendered in a template using tal like...

```
<div tal:replace="structure python: view.contents" />
```

I would like to render an onfocus attribute within the markup of the input. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give arbitrary HTML attribute parameters to z3c.form widgets in `updateWidgets()` phase of your form.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms/z3c.form.html#modifying-a-widget

HTML attributes for widgets:

http://svn.zope.org/z3c.form/trunk/src/z3c/form/browser/widget.py?rev=103729&view=auto

Comment: Many thanks, this was what I was trying to do but wasn't sure I was on the right lines as the widgets dict was empty. I was missing the line super(MyClass, self).updateWidgets() in my update method.